# Python 2.7 / Windows : Very odd behavior sending SMTP email

Tags: email, python-2.7

This has me totally stumped.  Here are two simple routines that send an email.  The first succeeds, the second (with some minor exception trapping) locks up Python (Cntl-C will not kill the session).  In addition I've determined that the quote type used for the "Subject" line matters.  So if I use

```
msg['Subject'] = "Random text"
```

The email will fail, but

```
msg['Subject'] = 'Random text'
```

this succeeds

Can someone please shine some light into the darkness:

Example #1

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
addr = "10.0.0.178"
From = "me@somewhere.net"
recip = ["me@somewherelese.net","foo@bar.net"]
msg = "Message Body"
send_email(recip,"Subject Line",msg)

def send_email(To,Subj,Mess):
    msg = MIMEText(Mess)
    msg["Subject"] = Subj
    msg['From'] = From
    s = smtplib.SMTP(addr)
    for entry in To:
        msg['To'] = entry
        s.sendmail(From, [entry], msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Example 2:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
addr = "10.0.0.178"
From = "me@somewhere.net"
recip = ["me@somewherelese.net","foo@bar.net"]
msg = "Message Body"
send_email(recip,"Subject Line",msg)

def send_email(To,Subj,Mess):
    msg = MIMEText(Mess)
    msg["Subject"] = Subj
    msg['From'] = From
    s = smtplib.SMTP(addr)
    for entry in To:
        msg['To'] = entry
        try:
            s.sendmail(From, [entry], msg.as_string())
        except:
            print "Error sending email"
    s.quit()
```